# Align <ul> <li> elements to the left

Tags: css

I'm having trouble aligning li elements to the left on tabs, as they are centered. I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I've tried a few things but always end up breaking the code.

Also, as a plus, the effects for fadein on divs don't seem to work on opera and firefox.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guisasso/6f6PY/

**CSS**

```
.tabs {
border-bottom:3px #f2f2f2 solid;
}

.tabs li {
list-style:none;
display:inline;
color:#08c;
}

.tabs a {
padding:5px 20px;
display:inline-block;
background:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
color:#08c;
top: 3px;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 140%;
padding-top: 10px;
background: #ffffff;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: relative;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
margin-bottom:3px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

}

.tabs a.active {
background: #ffffff;
border-bottom:3px orange solid;
color:#000000;
top:0px;
}
.tabs a:hover {
background: #f2f2f2;
top: 0px;
border-bottom:3px orange solid;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4 {
animation: fadein 1s;
-moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera */
 }
@keyframes fadein {
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">

<li><a href='#tab1'>Tab #1</a></li>
<li><a href='#tab2'>Tab #2</a></li>
<li><a href='#tab3'>Tab #3</a></li>
<li><a href='#tab4'>Tab #4</a></li>

</ul>

<div id="tab1">111111111111111 11111111111111111 1111111111111111111 1111111111111</div>
<div id="tab2">222222222222222 22222222222222222 2222222222222222222 2222222222222</div>
<div id="tab3">333333333333333 33333333333333333 3333333333333333333 3333333333333</div>
<div id="tab4">444444444444444 44444444444444444 4444444444444444444 4444444444444</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "to the left"?

Comment: For future reference, solutions to simple issues like this one will become more obvious if you use element inspector. You can right click on the area in question and there should be an option similar to "Inspect Element". This will allow you to hover over lines of your code and see padding and margins, as well as quickly test out solutions in the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to `.tabs`:

```
padding-left: 0;
```

Change in `.tabs a`:

```
padding: 5px 20px;
```

to

```
padding: 5px 20px 5px 0;
```

It doesn't get any lefter than that.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRL5H/